# Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type '(String?)' and 'String?'

Tags: swift

Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type '(String?)' and 'String?'

```
if (dictionary["firstKey"] as? String) > coreDataObject?.objectID as? String {

}
```

What type is '(String?)'?

Comment: An optional String. Which should be obvious, because you used as? instead of as. You have to figure out what you want to do if one of those objects isn't actually a String.

Comment: But why do I see one optional String with parenthesis?

Comment: In Swift, `if`-statements don't require parentheses around the condition. By putting them there, you're defining a tuple with a single element.

Comment: @MariusSchulz Parentheses can be used to group conditional expressions and subexpressions in Swift. Using parens in that manner doesn't define a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cristian points out, you have 2 optionals, which won't work.

As to why the error reports about type "(String?)", it looks like the compiler thinks the first part of your if statement is creating a tuple rather than defining the order of operation. That's something I'm not clear about in Swift - when do parentheses define a tuple, and when do they just determine operator precedence?

Try this:

```
if let firstKeyValue = dictionary["firstKey"] as String,
  let objectID = coreDataObject?.objectID as String
{
  if firstKeyValue > objectID
  {
     //your code here
  }
}
else
{
  //Error. Could not convert data to strings
}
```